# JS Prototype get element by class?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I got the following code and I'm trying to make it match on a class instead of on an id:

Html:

```
<div id='testdiv'>
    <div class="lol">
        [First Title|<a class="external" href="http://test.com">http://test.com</a>]
        Another line
        [Second Title|<a class="external" href="http://test.com">http://test.com</a>]
        More text
        [Third Title|<a class="external" href="http://test.com">http://test.com</a>]
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var textContainer = document.getElementById("testdiv");
var linkText = textContainer.innerHTML;
var pattern = /\[([^|]+)\|([^>]+.?)[^<]*(<\/a>)\]/g;
var result = linkText.replace(pattern, "$2$1$3");

textContainer.innerHTML = result;
```

Full example: http://jsfiddle.net/JFC72/17/

How can I make it match on "myclass" instead?
Thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use a [css selector](http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/dom/dollar-dollar/index.html) in prototype.

```
var textContainer = $$('div.myclass')[0];
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JFC72/19/)

Answer (score 11):

I think you need the `$$` method.  It selects DOM elements that match a CSS selector strict.  In this case you want

```
var elements = $$('.myclass');
```

It returns a list of all matching elements in document order.  You can access them by index or operating on all of them with things like `each`

http://www.prototypejs.org/api/utility

This is what Prototype is about.  getElementById is oooold

Answer (score 3):

Here is a working example of how you would use `each` in Prototype to loop through all elements with a class of `order-cc-charged`.

```
var order_cc_charged = 0;

$$('order-cc-charged').each(function (elem) {
   order_cc_charged += parseFloat($('order-cc-charged').innerHTML);
});
```